# How to format a date to a specific format in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-dateutil

I have a datetime from below generated code

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
tz = timezone('US/Pacific')
print(datetime.now(tz)) # 2019-06-17 05:41:22.189735-07:00
```

I am looking for this format of output

```
"Wed, 17 Jun 2019 05:41:22 -0700"
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) method:

```
print(datetime.now().strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to fix it myself by

```
print(datetime.now(tz).strftime("%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %z")) # Mon, 17 June 2019 05:51:16 -0700
```